# Laravel any route any doesnt get executed

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have tried the following in my laravel web routes

```
   Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
   })->where('any', '.*');;
```

But the above doesnt get called. I expect whenever i try calling any route not specified to use the above but it doesnt work.

I have checked on [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906333/laravel-5-1-route-doesnt-work) but still the issue persists. What could be the issue
I have also tried adding it like

```
    ///other routes above
   Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
   })->where('any', '*');
```

But still doesnt work.

Comment: try clear cache. php artisan route:clear. code looks good

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions in your where condition.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

In your case this should work:

```
  Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('welcome');
   })->whereAlphaNumeric('any');
```

this is equivalent to:

```
->where('any', '[a-zA-Z0-9]+');
```